# Existence of function in subset of Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $g\in W^{1.2}(\Omega)$ and $Tg\leq 0$ a.e., where $T$ is the trace operator. Let $X:=\{u\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)|u\geq g \text{ a.e.}\}$. We want to show that $X$ is non-empty. Can anyone offer some help? Thank you very much.

Comment: The function $u(x) =\max(0, g(x))$ should be in $X$, I think.

Comment: @daw But how to you conclude that such $u$ is weakly differentiable?

Comment: This is a standard result, it is an exercise in Evans book.